# ¿ Como hacer que no se recarguen las paginas en Chrome cuando cambio de pestaña?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Hola estoy teniendo problemas en Google Chrome.
Tengo abiertas varias pestañas y cuando cambio de una pestaña a otra, se recargan de nuevo.
Cada pestaña a la que entro se recarga de nuevo cada vez que cambio, mas bien es como si cuando salgo de una a otra, la que abandono comenzara ya a recargarse, y no termina de hacerlo hasta que vuelvo a ella y permanezco en la misma.
No debilite cookies ni nada por el estilo
No hice ningún cambio en la configuración, por lo que no se como corregir esto y que las pestañas permanezcan donde las deje.
¿ Como podría corregir esto para que las paginas permanezcan como las deje al cambiar de pestaña ?
Gracias

Comment: es para ahorrar memoria, lo podes des habilitar yendo a chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

Comment: Gracias @aloMalbarez, pero no se como proceder, entre en la pagina pero esta en ingles. No se cual desabilitar...

Comment: automatic tab discarding significa "descartar pestañas automáticamente" y al lado hay un selector que dice default, lo cambias a disabled. el texto de explicación lo podes traducir con [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/If%20enabled%2C%20tabs%20get%20automatically%20discarded%20from%20memory%20when%20the%20system%20memory%20is%20low.%20Discarded%20tabs%20are%20still%20visible%20on%20the%20tab%20strip%20and%20get%20reloaded%20when%20clicked%20on.%20Info%20about%20discarded%20tabs%20can%20be%20found%20at%20chrome%3A%2F%2Fdiscards.)

Comment: Gracias @aloMalbarez, si pones como respuesta, estare encantada de aceptarla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso se debe al Tab discarding (descartar pestañas), que es una opción que le permite a Chrome ahorrar memoria eligiendo pestañas que considera no se usan y descargarlas de memoria. La opción [está disponible desde la versión 46](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding)

En un momento fue una opción experimental, hoy en día ya viene activada en la instalación. Para desactivarla hay que ir a la página de opciones internas de Chrome, poner en la barra de direcciones : `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding`.

`Automatic tab discarding` significa "descartar pestañas automáticamente" y al lado de la descripción vas a ver un selector que dice `Default`, lo cambiás a `Disabled` y se desactiva.

Como son opciones de desarrollo muchas de ellas experimentales, no cuentan con traducción al español, pero usando [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/If%20enabled%2C%20tabs%20get%20automatically%20discarded%20from%20memory%20when%20the%20system%20memory%20is%20low.%20Discarded%20tabs%20are%20still%20visible%20on%20the%20tab%20strip%20and%20get%20reloaded%20when%20clicked%20on.%20Info%20about%20discarded%20tabs%20can%20be%20found%20at%20chrome%3A%2F%2Fdiscards.) podemos leerlo tranquilamente y despejar algunas dudas de que hace cada cosa.

> Automatic tab discarding
>
> If enabled, tabs get automatically discarded from memory when the system memory is low. Discarded tabs are still visible on the tab strip and get reloaded when clicked on. Info about discarded tabs can be found at `chrome://discards`. – Mac, Windows

---

> Descarte automático de pestañas
>
> Si está habilitado, las pestañas se descartan automáticamente de la memoria cuando la memoria del sistema es baja. Las pestañas descartadas aún son visibles en la barra de pestañas y se vuelven a cargar cuando se hace clic en ellas. Puede encontrar información sobre las pestañas descartadas en `chrome://discards`. - Mac, Windows