# Evitar refresh automático de navegadores con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Holaaaaaa, quisiera saber si hay algún código en php o javascript o jquery, o html, talvez metatag, lo que sea, que evite que luego de un tiempo se refresque automáticamente una página.

Tengo un código ajax que se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo con setInterval, y cuando uso otras páginas normal sigue ejecutandose siempre en cuando la pestaña de mi web esté abierta, pero luego de una hora masomenos deja de funcionar y cuando entro a la pestaña a ver qué pasó, se refresca automáticamente. Quiero que siga funcionando todo el día el setinterval sin problemas.

Comment: Si tienes el codigo, deberas colocarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198223/81450, también se evita el discard con la opción pin tab ( botón derecho sobre el tab )

Comment: el código es simple, con un set interval solicito cada cierto tiempo información del servidor a travez de ajax y un php, el php devuelve si hay o no hay información, y si hay información se reproduce un tono en mp3 con javascript, nada más

Comment: alo Marlbarez, vi esa pregunta pero ahí cada uno de mis usuarios tendrían que hacer eso manualmente en su navegador, lo cual es imposible, por eso quiero saber si hay algún código que debo agregar a mi codigo fuente para evitar que mi página se recargue, o talvez algo en el -htaccess, no lo sé, eso es lo que quiero saber

Comment: Creo que lo más importante sería ver porqué se recarga la página si no tienes una instrucción para que lo haga. Probablemente se trata de una mala [gestión de memoria](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Gestion_de_Memoria)

Comment: eso pasa en todas las pcs y celulares creo, simplemente cuando dejas una pestaña abierta pero estás usando otra pestaña y no abres la anterior por mucho tiempo, cuando tratas de entrar nuevamente se refresca la página automáticamente, creo que es un lapso de una hora masomenos, por ejemplo si dejo esta pestaña de stackoverflow abierta y estoy mirando mi fb en otra pestaña, y pasa una hora y vuelvo a la pestaña de stackoverflow, se recarga automáticamente por haber estado mucho tiempo sin usar, eso quiero evitar en mi web

Comment: Aumenta los recursos de la máquina

Comment: @ArturoRodas no necesariamente amigo, nosotros salvo en otros contextos no necesitariamos ejecutar ese codigo, en este caso seria para guiarnos y saber como tienes exactamente estructurado o como haces la llamada a ajax y desde que funcion la estas llamando, como la estas llamando y etc, significa que en tu contexto se trata de algo que no es 100% necesario ejecutar, por eso te pedimos que coloques el codigo que haz realizado, no te preocupes porque nosotros no podamos ejecutarlo, pues si ese fuera el caso entonces no habrian preguntas sobre ajax aca en stackoverflow.

Comment: Esto es raro, no recuerdo que me haya pasado dejar pestañas abiertas y se tengan que recargar.